# Calculating how many elements are in the product of Cartesian multiplication

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A = \{1,3\}, B = \{1, 2\}, C = \{1, 2,3\}$.

How many elements are there in the set
$\{(x,y,z) \in A \times B \times C  | x + y = z \} $ ?

Two things I'm not familiar with here,

First, how do I do Cartesian multiplication between 3 sets?

And I'm having trouble figuring how the $x+y=z$ has to do with the number of elements?

Can you please show me how to solve this?

thanks :)

Comment: The Cartesian product of the sets is just the set of triplets $(a,b,c)$. Now you want to find all of the triplets $(a,b,c)$ that satisfies the property $a+b=c$. As an example, $1+2=3$, where $1$ is in $A$, $2$ is in $B$, and $3$ is in $C$. Does this help?

Comment: So I need to list all the combinations manually, and check which of the triplets follow the condition x+y=z?

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cartesian product of the three sets $A$, $B$, and $C$ is just the triplet $(a,b,c)$ such that $a∈ A$, $b∈B$, and $c∈C$. We wish to find any and all $(a,b,c)$ that satisfies the property $a+b=c$, where $a∈ A$, $b∈B$, and $c∈C$.

So $1+1=2$, and $1∈A$, $1∈B$, and $2∈C$, so we found one element, namely $(1,1,2)$.
$1+2 = 3$, and $1∈A$, $2∈B$, and $3∈C$, so we found another element, namely $(1,2,3)$.

Notice that $(1,1,3)$ is in $A×B×C$, but $1+1\neq3$, so $(1,1,3)$ is not an element.

Since our sets are small, we can repeat this process and then count how many elements you found that satisfy that property.

**Edit:** looks like that's all of them.

Comment: Do you see more than 2 combinations here? cause I don't :) just clarifying